# How to do I output Calculated numbers with Strings and JOptionPane?

Tags: java, string, joptionpane

I am trying to get Data to display beside each of the planet names, I have tried a few different ways but cannot get my script to display the numbers that are calculated.

```
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;

class planetAgeCalculator  {

public static void main(String[] args) {

JOptionPane box = new JOptionPane();

String firstNumber = 
box.showInputDialog(null, "Enter your age to find out how old you would be on the 9 planets ");

int number1 = Integer.parseInt( firstNumber);


    Runnable r = new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            String pt1 = "<html><body width='";
            String pt2 =
                "'><h1>Your age on different Planets: </h1>" +
                "<p>Mercury: " +
                "<p>Venus: " +
                "<p>Earth: " +
                "<p>Mars: " +
                "<p>Jupiter: " +
                "<p>Saturn: " +
                "<p>Uranus: " +
                "<p>Neptune: " +
                "<p>Pluto: " +
                "";


            JPanel p = new JPanel( new BorderLayout() );

            int width = 0;
            String s = pt1 + width + pt2 + width ;

            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, s);
        }
    };
    SwingUtilities.invokeLater(r);
}
}
```

Other than that it runs great....

Is it possible to incorporate data like i am trying to do with this method?

I have the calculations figured out I just cant get it to display the numbers.. when i input for instance..

```
"<p>Venus: " + (number1 * 5 / 3) +
```

I just get a ton of errors... is this even possible the way im trying to do it?

Thanks

Comment: *I am also having trouble getting rid of that 0 after "Pluto:"* remove the last `width` in your `String s`

Comment: I thought i had tried that previously but it wouldnt run, i probably missed a detail or broke the phrase somehow. That aspect is now fixed... but as far as getting numbers to display based on user input goes.. any ideas?

Comment: _"I just get a ton of errors_"  Please specific the errors

Comment: The only issue I have with `"<p>Venus: " + (number1 * 5 / 3) + ` is the fact that the next line is `+ "<p>Earth: "` is means you doing `"<p>Venus: " + (number1 * 5 / 3) + + "<p>Earth: "` which is obviously invalid, remove the trailing `+`, that seems to compile fine for me

Comment: planetAgeCalculator.java:21: error: ';' expected
                    "<p>Mercury: " + (number1 * 4) "" +
                                                  ^
1 error


this is the error i get, a simple semi colon expected error

Comment: `(number1 * 4) ""` is what then for you? a string or an integer?

Comment: This question was caused by a problem that can no longer be reproduced or a simple typographical error. While similar questions may be on-topic here, this one was resolved in a manner unlikely to help future readers. This can often be avoided by identifying and closely inspecting the shortest program necessary to reproduce the problem before posting.

Answer (score 0):

> I have the calculations figured out I just cant get it to display the
>   numbers.. when i input for instance..

You need to add `""` after the `+`. Or remove the `+` in the next line.

Try this

```
+ "<p>Venus: "+(number1 * 5 / 3) +""
```

Comment: `"<p>Venus: " + "<p>Earth: " +` there is another string anyway after the evaluation. I don't think this should be the possible reason OP is looking for. Or else I would vote it as Off-topic rather than answering it.

Comment: Hey

     "<p>Mercury: " + (number1 * 4) "" + 

for instance.. is what i'm inputing and the error i get is

    planetAgeCalculator.java:21: error: ';' expected
                    "<p>Mercury: " + (number1 * 4) "" +

Comment: use `+"<p>Mercury: " + (number1 * 4)` for that line